# Wifi problems when I use Bluetooth on my laptop

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, intel

Whenever I use my Bluetooth on my laptop, which is almost always since I use a bluetooth mouse, my internet speed falls to 1MB/s in the internet panel and almost nothing loads.

I'm using the iwlwifi drivers.

If I try to reconnect, it doesn't work - only disabling my laptop mouse works. If I keep Bluetooth on and not use any Bluetooth devices it does work.

How can I fix this? These problems only occur on my laptop when running Ubuntu.

Note that both Bluetooth and wifi work fine, only that once I try to use both, I lose my wifi connection.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a Dell 15z, using Bluetooth nukes the wifi connection. I'm thinking this might be a bug, because I also noticed that turning off bluetooth also disables wifi on this cmop.

Comment: I'm having the same. Laptop is Toshiba r830.
dmesg shows some info: ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -5
ath: phy0: Unable to set channel
ath: phy0: Could not kill baseband RX

Comment: [Possibly the same as this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/567097/wifi-slows-down-if-i-connect-with-bluetooth-device-on-ubuntu-14-10)

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and never responded to any comments. Question is also about EOL Ubuntu version. VTC as `not reproducible`.