# Can only have either WiFi or Bluetooth active

Tags: 14.04, wireless, bluetooth, vaio, intel-wireless

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, (currently installed 14.04) activating bluetooth makes my wireless extremely slow (halt). I managed to fix the problem recently with the help of this topic:
[Wifi slows down if I connect with Bluetooth device on Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567097/wifi-slows-down-if-i-connect-with-bluetooth-device-on-ubuntu-14-10)

However, the same problem appeared again today: I can either have bluetooth or wifi but not both at the same time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit, 
output of the two commands:

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN [8086:5201]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

lsusb

```
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ca:18c0 Ricoh Co., Ltd 
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 08ff:168f AuthenTec, Inc. AES1660 Fingerprint Sensor    
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and `lsusb` terminal commands.

Answer (score 0):

With the iwlwifi module there is a bluetooth coexistence parameter that is set to enable by default but since it doesn't seem to be working for you, we can disable it with

```
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Reboot and see if it works better

Comment: Thank you Jeremy31! This solved the problem. I first had to restart bluetooth: `sudo service bluetooth restart` and then edit the iwlwifi.conf as you suggested + restart the computer.