# Wifi connection slows down when bluetooth speaker is connected

Tags: 16.04, wireless, bluetooth

I have a 20mb/s wifi connection and it works properly unless I connect my bluetooth speaker. when I do that the wifi connection slows down and poorly work. I've already tryed [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567097/wifi-slows-down-if-i-connect-with-bluetooth-device-on-ubuntu-14-10) and this [other one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645009/wi-fi-and-bluetooth-not-working-simultaneously)
but none of that worked. I'm running a Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron 14300.

The outputs for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` are:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
```

And also, the outputs for `lsusb` are:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 062a:4102 Creative Labs 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I don't know what else I can do to fix it.

Comment: bluetooth is a frequency filter on the wifi, so it is expected for wifi to slow when bluetooth is active because some of the time is spent broadcasting the bluetooth.  How much is it slowing?

Comment: I can't even open youtube and listen to spotify's online playlists. But when I turn off the bluetooth the connection starts working normaly in a sec

Comment: Check this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364633

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable BT coexistence in the `ath9k` module.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf <<< "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1"
```

and reboot.

This helps in most cases. The `ath9k` BT coex algorithm is good. It is a shame that it isn't enabled by default yet.

Comment: makes sense that it should be enabled by default

Comment: Long ago it didn't work well on some devices, that's why they didn't enable it. With Intel devices it works poorly, but is enabled.

Comment: I remember 14.04 didn't have the ath9k firmware, I had to go find it. If I remember correctly intel's firmware worked :)

Comment: @ravery This is not related to any firmware.

Comment: @Pilot6,  Like I said, it worked at first try, but past some time the wifi connection started fail again...

Comment: Not worked for me with ubuntu 18.04