# Wifi slows down when Bluetooth headset is connected in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, sound, bluetooth

My wifi works perfectly until I connect my system to a Bluetooth headset. After connecting to the Bluetooth headset my wifi slows down a lot. I tried solution from [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/567097/1112104) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/645009/1112104)
questions but nothing worked.

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Sanji2 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

thanks in advance :)

**`Edit 1`**

Output of `sudo iwlist freq`

```
lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

wlo1      13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
```

**`Edit 2`**

`ant_sel=1` doesn't gives any noticeable change

`ant_sel=2` results in 'no network found` (Ubuntu unable to find any wifi network)

```
parag@Notebook:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf 
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2 swlps=0
parag@Notebook:~$ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|level'
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

[image]

also Output of `modeinfo rtl8723be`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     17AE822AE3E2EAA1A500831
alias:          pci:v000010ECd0000B723sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8723be
vermagic:       5.11.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        0D:27:87:4B:73:30:80:92:F7:26:14:3F:FE:83:1E:48:91:08:F2:86
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      43:63:EC:A3:6A:63:26:D9:16:9F:D5:8C:B0:B9:D5:24:FF:D7:FD:39:
        89:57:BA:4A:F1:87:DD:8A:90:6F:8B:C7:78:77:59:E5:E4:6C:93:B8:
        42:94:86:8A:4F:62:AA:29:DA:C8:AC:6D:D5:19:15:36:24:7D:2A:E7:
        7D:C7:70:2E:69:35:28:17:42:A0:68:05:20:FB:64:1C:75:5D:CA:B7:
        A2:51:81:00:08:93:54:2A:7B:3B:1A:3F:33:0D:E9:B9:5C:E2:30:15:
        E2:59:C5:96:BE:B0:CE:5F:72:8E:63:B4:4E:10:62:F8:7E:A1:27:9C:
        AA:7C:47:E0:5C:59:E7:68:E9:B4:5F:2B:3D:83:59:0B:E9:AD:61:48:
        21:F9:60:CC:BC:BA:3F:4E:25:7F:72:DA:87:07:96:F6:F5:EF:E7:4E:
        67:7E:77:67:74:11:1C:7D:A7:E2:54:7E:45:BE:D9:21:AF:AE:E1:BA:
        68:DB:0A:1E:2A:33:35:B5:8C:E4:ED:F4:3A:98:08:80:E3:BB:19:C6:
        B6:CC:57:1F:1B:BC:6F:DA:A0:F3:87:48:E3:F4:F6:0B:1B:06:4F:A9:
        C9:F3:5F:40:A4:D2:BF:BF:19:C5:ED:0F:6E:25:2A:41:93:CC:E8:D9:
        F1:6F:3E:AD:EB:80:3C:F9:53:E4:91:12:3D:EE:6C:70:B6:DB:73:8A:
        01:D8:84:56:D9:CE:28:D1:8D:55:07:EF:D5:CB:71:23:3F:63:21:07:
        BB:F9:FF:DC:DD:24:85:B5:DA:0A:60:A9:D1:49:ED:52:97:72:CB:87:
        96:7F:FD:85:EA:35:55:E9:AD:D6:3E:D2:43:23:C2:11:26:7B:57:C9:
        71:24:32:35:FE:5D:80:56:CD:4C:EC:1A:54:65:64:78:0D:88:32:08:
        2C:97:0B:D6:2C:36:20:F6:66:C2:FC:AB:55:E6:DB:82:52:ED:00:70:
        E3:28:B9:5C:BE:A1:88:8A:3A:F4:C9:E5:6E:A6:4A:2D:DB:7B:5F:49:
        86:C6:4C:4E:9C:62:BD:23:60:23:8C:46:54:B2:CA:79:63:2A:82:B1:
        46:4B:97:CC:3B:64:57:BD:70:AD:CE:3F:DC:42:D2:B1:C0:13:BB:4C:
        72:A4:0F:9A:C3:0B:84:01:E8:B9:53:0C:80:DB:8E:E2:46:12:B1:B1:
        73:35:F9:94:3A:FD:7F:1A:22:91:B8:1F:BA:DA:87:97:9A:CF:D5:A9:
        08:B7:62:B6:6E:28:64:84:50:C2:D2:7B:B7:BB:98:12:62:26:CC:FB:
        A3:FE:8D:F7:4F:AD:C3:C6:EF:62:DC:A6:02:8C:5D:1F:26:E7:30:D0:
        30:4E:A2:04:3C:EE:9A:9D:A5:C1:24:A1
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1)
 (int)
parm:           debug_level:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)
 (int)
```

**`Edit 3`**

1. Output of commands

```
parag@Notebook:~$ uname -a
Linux Notebook 5.11.0-25-generic #27~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 13 17:41:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

parag@Notebook:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 30:e1:71:73:d8:3f
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-25-generic firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b1200fff memory:b1000000-b1003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 58:00:e3:88:1f:93
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=5.11.0-25-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b1103fff

parag@Notebook:~$ ls -al /etc/pm/config.d/
ls: cannot access '/etc/pm/config.d/': No such file or directory

parag@Notebook:~$ ls -al /etc/modprobe.d/
total 60
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 13 13:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 137 root root 12288 Aug 12 15:51 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2507 Jul 31  2015 alsa-base.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   154 Feb 16  2020 amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   325 Mar 12  2020 blacklist-ath_pci.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1518 Mar 12  2020 blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   210 Mar 12  2020 blacklist-firewire.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   677 Mar 12  2020 blacklist-framebuffer.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   156 Jul 31  2015 blacklist-modem.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    41 Jul 17 22:15 blacklist-oss.conf -> /lib/linux-sound-base/noOSS.modprobe.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   583 Mar 12  2020 blacklist-rare-network.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   154 Nov 12  2020 intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   347 Mar 12  2020 iwlwifi.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    28 Aug 14 08:18 rtl8723be.conf

parag@Notebook:~$ sudo lsmod | grep rtl8723be
rtl8723be              98304  0
btcoexist             155648  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                94208  4 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,btcoexist,rtl8723_common
mac80211             1024000  3 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,rtlwifi

parag@Notebook:~$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"FTTH-5731"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: 00:6D:61:D8:57:31   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:857   Missed beacon:0

parag@Notebook:~$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Kernel: 5.11.0-25-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Notebook v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: HP model: 81EB v: 61.38 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde v: F.21 date: 10/27/2016 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 28.6 Wh condition: 32.6/32.1 Wh (101%) model: Hewlett-Packard PABAS0241231 status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i3-6006U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Skylake rev: 3 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 15999 
           Speed: 1800 MHz min/max: 400/2000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1803 2: 1926 3: 1802 4: 1816 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: i915 resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-25-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 4000 
           bus ID: 01:00.0 
           IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtl8723be v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 26.69 GiB (2.9%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10JPVX-60JC3T0 size: 931.51 GiB temp: 37 C 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 48.97 GiB used: 26.66 GiB (54.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 45.5 C mobo: 29.8 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 295 Uptime: 29m Memory: 7.67 GiB used: 3.59 GiB (46.8%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A 
           Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

2. `Brand/Model of computer` : HP 15-ay542tu
3. Stay's like this
   [image]

Also

1. setting swlps=0

```
parag@Notebook:~$ sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be swlps=0 fwlps=0"
options rtl8723be swlps=0 fwlps=0
parag@Notebook:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
options rtl8723be swlps=0 fwlps=0
parag@Notebook:~$ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
                    ESSID:"FTTH-5731"
```

Outputs

`Internet Speed difference` (average of 3 readings from [fast.com](http://fast.com))

```
12.3Mbps (without bluetooth headset)
1.8Mbps (with buletooth headset)
```

```
parag@Notebook:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
options rtl8723be swlps=0 fwlps=0
parag@Notebook:~$ grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ant_sel:0
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/aspm:1
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/debug_level:0
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/debug_mask:0
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/disable_watchdog:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/fwlps:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ips:Y
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/msi:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swenc:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swlps:N
parag@Notebook:~$ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    ESSID:"FTTH-5731"
```

2. ant_sel=1

```
parag@Notebook:~$ sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
options rtl8723be ant_sel=1
parag@Notebook:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
options rtl8723be ant_sel=1
parag@Notebook:~$ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
                    ESSID:"FTTH-5731"
```

Outputs

`speed`: no major difference

```
parag@Notebook:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
options rtl8723be ant_sel=1
parag@Notebook:~$ grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ant_sel:1
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/aspm:1
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/debug_level:0
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/debug_mask:0
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/disable_watchdog:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/fwlps:Y
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ips:Y
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/msi:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swenc:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swlps:N
parag@Notebook:~$ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    ESSID:"FTTH-5731"
```

3. ant_sel=2

```
parag@Notebook:~$ sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2
parag@Notebook:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2
parag@Notebook:~$ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    ESSID:"FTTH-5731"
```

Outputs:

No wifi network was found in setting -> wifi

```
parag@Notebook:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2
parag@Notebook:~$ grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ant_sel:2
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/aspm:1
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/debug_level:0
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/debug_mask:0
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/disable_watchdog:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/fwlps:Y
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ips:Y
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/msi:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swenc:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swlps:N
parag@Notebook:~$ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

4. No difference

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue some months back and get it solved by using Wi-Fi on 5 GHz band. Basically, bluetooth uses 2.4 GHz band. If Wi-Fi also uses the same band, there will be some interference between those. So, changing the Wi-Fi to 5GHz band and using bluetooth on 2.4 GHz solves the problem.

In my case, when Wi-Fi is connected, bluetooth headset's latency was increased. And after doing some research online, I found the solution. Switching bands greatly improved things.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I don't have a  5GHz band for wifi

Comment: You can also try changing the channel and its width in Wi-Fi router.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Settings are different for different manufacturers. Please refer to your routers manual. You may google it too. :)

Comment: Wait...but these are channel of my laptop so changing router will not going to help...also 80% of time I use mobile hotspot

Comment: @ParagKatoch the laptop's wifi card uses what the router provides. You can set your mobile hotspot to 5Ghz in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

### Info to post

Please post the following info

1. Output of commands

   ```
    $ uname -a
    $ sudo lshw -class network
    $ modinfo rtl8723be          <-- DONE
    $ ls -al /etc/pm/config.d/
    $ ls -al /etc/modprobe.d/
    $ sudo iwlist freq           <-- DONE
    $ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2  <-- DONE
    $ sudo lsmod | grep rtl8723be
    $ sudo iwconfig
    $ inxi -Fxz
   ```
2. Brand/model of your computer
3. Where did you see "'no network found' (Ubuntu unable to find any wifi network)" after using `ant_sel=2`?

### Things to try

1. Setting option `swlps=0` (somehow it is not set at that default as of now). Run these commands and post the output and resulting behavior.

   ```
    $ sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be swlps=0 fwlps=0"
    $ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
    $ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
   ```

   Reboot

   ```
    $ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
    $ grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*
    $ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
   ```
2. Setting option `ant_sel=1`. Run these commands and post the output and resulting behavior.

   ```
    $ sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
    $ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
    $ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
   ```

   Reboot

   ```
    $ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
    $ grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*
    $ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
   ```
3. Setting option `ant_sel=2`. Run these commands and post the output and resulting behavior.

   ```
    $ sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"
    $ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
    $ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
   ```

   Reboot

   ```
    $ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
    $ grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*
    $ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
   ```
4. Disabling the 5GHz band in the router.
   Post the resulting behavior.

### Notes

1. Compiling a new driver (often using a driver from Larry Finger) solved the problem for many people, but all those posts are old, so I guess it is not a problem-solver as of now.
   See e.g., [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=208472), [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079892/226614), [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=219125).
2. It seems some HP models do not have both antennas cabled, see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304607&p=13401836#post13401836), [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1148622#p1148622), [this](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-RTL8723BE-Wi-Fi-Adapter-upgrade/td-p/6070356).
3. I would also try removing the option for coexistence, but there seems to be no option at the driver level for this. There is a dependence on `btcoexist`, but I wouldn't know how to use that, perhaps someone else knows.

**Did it work well at any time?**
If so, you could try [booting to an older kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version), at least to test further alternatives below.

---

Interference between bluetooth and wifi is well known, I am listing below a few sources, which include general methods of avoiding it.

In Ubuntu, the way to implement those methods are by setting options for the driver.
Run in a terminal

```
$ sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
```

and reboot.
You might need/try

```
$ sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

If that doesn't work, try with `ant_sel=2`.
If that doesn't work either, other options may help.
I don't have an `rtl8723be` to test, but you could [post the output](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) of

```
$ modinfo rtl8723be
```

to get a list.

Note that solutions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/618405/226614) (distancing bluetooth and wifi adapters), or changing the band, do not work for you, since [Realtek RTL873BE](https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8723be) is a "802.11bgn PCIe WLAN with Bluetooth 4.0 Single-Chip Controller" (single band, 2.4GHz).

**Ubuntu sources**:

1. [Bluetooth Audio interfering with WiFi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060094/bluetooth-audio-interfering-with-wifi)
2. [Wi-Fi connectivity issue - Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074962/wi-fi-connectivity-issue-ubuntu-18-04)
3. [Realtek RTL8723BE Wi-Fi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak)
4. [Realtek RTL8723be doesn't have good reception](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717685/realtek-rtl8723be-doesnt-have-good-reception)
5. [Wi-Fi connectivity issue - Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074962/wi-fi-connectivity-issue-ubuntu-18-04)
6. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384889
7. https://infinitecoder.github.io/posts/2017-12-09-rtl8723be-fix/

**General sources**:

1. [How to Stop Bluetooth Interference From Messing With Your Other Devices](https://www.goldtouch.com/stop-bluetooth-interference-messing-devices/)
2. [WiFi and Bluetooth interference – diagnosing and fixing](https://www.codejourney.net/2017/04/wifi-and-bluetooth-interference-diagnosing-and-fixing/)
3. [How to Avoid Bluetooth Interference in Headphones](https://www.headphonesty.com/2021/01/bluetooth-interference/)
4. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-stop-my-bluetooth-headphones-from-interfering-with-my-WIFI-signal

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try all the methods this evening :)

Comment: I have edited my question with the output

Comment: @preIdiot - Please see EDIT. In addition, please copy-paste what you get on-screen instead of posting "ant_sel=2 results in 'no network found`". It increases the chance of understanding *exactly* the problem. And avoid screenshots if posting output from a terminal (just in case you are tempted to do that).

Comment: edited, and this problem exists from the start.

Comment: @preIdiot _ I see you did not provide all requested info. I made an ordered list. If you could follow it item by item, that will help me help you.

Comment: I have edited the question with required details. I don't understand why my system is unable to list wifi networks with ant_sel=2, while other users problem is solved with it.