# 20.04 w/ Wireless-AC 9462 - Disconnects after 1-2 hours, Unclaimed

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I installed Server 20.04 on a brand new Intel NUC and as usual the installation was flawless.  Installed Network Manager and connected to an AP, also no issue.

After about 12 hours the system went offline.  I did 'lshw -C network' and found the Wifi adapter in "UNCLAIMED" status.  I rebooted and it came back, connected, no issues - for 2 hours, then it went offline and was in unclaimed status again.

Here's the lshw output when it's working:

```
*-network:0               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9462
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: 28:df:eb:14:1c:6b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-90-generic firmware=50.3e391d3e.0 ip=10.1.0.254 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6023114000-6023117fff
```

I've read about backports but most of that is from last year and 18.04.  I don't think it's a powersave issue since it ran for 12 hours the first time, and only an hour or 2 the second time.

Wired access isn't a viable option where this device is, so I'd really like to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Related? https://askubuntu.com/a/1372187/226614  https://askubuntu.com/a/1365809/226614

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.